# BLE GAP Profle through GATT on Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am working on BLE using BlueZ-4.101 stack,i have been able to port all the necessary binaries,and able to connect two devices.

I am creating connection using command:
gatttool -i hci0 -b  -I
connect
i.e opening the interactive mode and connect through it.
When I try to discover primary services of the other connected device , it shows 
**Discover all primary services failed: A timeout Occured**

Where I am going wrong ,can anyone point out ? How can we check primary services of our own device ?
Actually Device Information Service has to be implemented with this stack,can anyone list out the steps on this?

Comment: Are you passing a MAC Address with your gatttool command? Also, do you know what is the type of address of the device you are trying to connect to? Try using this command and see what happens: #gatttool -t random -b <MAC Address> --primary, but first, make sure that you can see the device you are trying to connect to with the #hcitool lescan command.

Comment: Our Mac address is public,not random. However I tried this command but,its not able to connect and on the peripheral device I am getting segmentation fault and bluetooth daemon gets killed.This behaviour is same without using the random flag given.

Comment: And I'm able to see my device using `hcitool lescan` command.
Many times I also get the `Connection refused(111) connect error`

Comment: How can we check that we have default enable LE connectable undirected advertising in the Gatt server side? As with the bluez 4.101 we don't have such options `hciconfig hci0 leadv 0` to make it connectable

Comment: One of the problem is resolved. For connecting to the ble device, I firstly did the pairing using the `bt-device` binary, as I don't have the python setup on the target board so didn't used `simple-agent`. I got the primary services and characteristics listed. But the connection is not stable. It disconnects itself after random time. Also the advertise disables on the peripheral end. Why is it so?

Comment: You probably need proper debugging on the peripheral and central side to find out the actual reason. Try using #hcidump and #btmon to see what is exactly happening to the raw data.

Comment: hcidump on the peripheral side shows `Reason: Connection Timeout`

Comment: Also please comment for the steps to implement the DIS in ble

Comment: I have been able to get the characteristics of DIS and through command line I am able to read its ASCCII value.Is there any Application through which I can discover the service and read its proper value?

Comment: We were able to read the values through application by creating conf file for it and parsing it in our code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try pairing to the remote device before connecting to it through gatttool.

For pairing you can use `simple-agent` or `bt-device` utilities.

To implement the DIS, you can look how the GATT and GAP are implemented, similar way you can add the attributes and handles for the DIS characteristics.

I hope it will be helpful.